# Existence of a particular vector in kernal of $d \exp_x$

Tags: linear-algebra, riemannian-geometry

I want to prove

$(d\exp_x)_{p}$ is singular iff there exists a normal Jacobi field $U(t)$ along $\gamma(t)=\exp_x(tp)$ not identically zero such that $U(0)=U(1)=0$.

---

I have question about $(\implies)$ direction. By normal Jacobi field, I mean $\langle U(t),\gamma'(t)\rangle=0$.

Since $(d\exp_x)_p$ is nondegenerate in the direction of $p$. Therefore we only need to consider $X$ s.t. $\langle X,p\rangle=0$

Let $X\in T_xM\simeq T_p(T_xM)$ s.t. $\langle X,p\rangle=0$ Then $\gamma_u(t)=\exp_x[t(p+uX)]$ gives a normal Jacobi field with $U(0)=0,U'(0)=X, U(1)=(d\exp_x)_p(X)$.

Therefor if $X\in \ker((d\exp_x)_p)$ and $X\not=0$ then $U(t)$ is the required normal Jacobi field.

But I am not sure whether such $X$ exists. That is given $p\not\in  \ker((d\exp_x)_p)$, find $X\in \ker((d\exp_x)_p)$ such that $X\not=0, \langle X,p\rangle=0$. I know if $\dim \ker((d\exp_x)_p)>1$, it's possible. But I am not sure how to handle $\dim \ker((d\exp_x)_p)=1$. Is there any property of $d\exp_x$ that I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gauss lemma states that for $X\in T_xM$ we have$$\langle d(\exp_x)_p(X),d(\exp_x)_p(p)\rangle=\langle X,p\rangle.$$It follows that the kernel of $d(\exp_x)_p$ is contained in the orthogonal complement of $p$, as you conjectured.

Comment: Oh, I haven't learnt this version of Gauss lemma. What I have learnt is $\langle p,X\rangle=0\implies \langle d(\exp_x)_p(X),d(\exp_x)_p(p)\rangle=0$ Thanks for letting me know the other direction.

Comment: @JohnZHANG The version I quoted follows quite easily from the one you do, since we also know $\langle d(\exp_x)_p(p), d(\exp_x)_p(p)\rangle=\langle p,p\rangle$.